# Left Outer Stream-Stream SELF join using Spark Structured Streaming - Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to do a stream-stream self join using Spark Structured streaming using a left outer join so that I can split the joined and unjoined rows after.
My setup is as follows:

```
df_source = app.spark.readStream.format("kafka") \
                 .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "XXXXXXX") \
                 .option("subscribe", "XXXXXXX") \
                 .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
                 .option("kafka.group.id", "924ee006-c268-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002") \
                 .load() \

df_source.createOrReplaceTempView("df_source")
```

I then incrementally get the json string from the kafka message and parse the json into my required schema:

```
df0 = app.spark.sql("""\
----------------------
SELECT
    CAST(value AS STRING) AS json
FROM df_source
----------------------
""")

df0.createOrReplaceTempView("df0")
```

```
df1 = app.spark.sql("""\
----------------------
SELECT
    from_json(json,        'struct< `metadata`   : struct< `namespace` : string 
                                                         , `name`      : string
                                                         , `name0`     : string 
                                                         , `size0`     : int
                                                         , `message0`  : struct< `id`           : string
                                                                               , `type`         : string
                                                                               , `timestamp`    : string
                                                                               , `date`         : string
                                                                               , `time`         : string
                                                                               , `process_name` : string
                                                                               , `loglevel`     : string
                                                                               , `process_id`   : string
                                                                               >
                                                         >
                                  , `spec`       : struct< `fix`                  : string
                                                         , `source_process_name`  : string
                                                         , `sink_process_name`    : string
                                                         , `source_CLORDID`       : string
                                                         , `sink_CLORDID`         : string
                                                         , `action`               : string
                                  >
                                  , `@timestamp` : timestamp
                                  >
                           ')               AS dict
FROM df0
----------------------
""")

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
```

I am trying to perform a self join on df1 where dict.spec.sink_CLORDID == dict.spec.source_CLORDID.
I have followed the [spark structured streaming docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#operations-on-streaming-dataframesdatasets)

I am defining a watermark based on my event-timestamp:

```
df1_new = df1.withWatermark("`dict.@timestamp`", "2 minutes")
```

Then I am trying to do the self-join:

```
df2 = df1.alias("orig").join(df1_new.alias("new"), 
                     expr("""
                         orig.dict.spec.sink_CLORDID = new.dict.spec.source_CLORDID AND
                         \"new.dict.@timestamp\" >= \"orig.dict.@timestamp\" AND
                         \"new.dict.@timestamp\" <= \"orig.dict.@timestamp\" + interval 1 minute
                    """),
                     "leftOuter"
                )
```

But I am receiving the following error message:

Stream-stream LeftOuter join between two streaming DataFrame/Datasets is not supported without a watermark in the join keys, or a watermark on the nullable side and an appropriate range condition

I have a few questions:

1. I have followed the docs example in regards to the join exactly, why am i still getting a watermark error?
2. As I am incrementally defining dataframes from stream -> dataset I want to join do I need to define a watermark for all of them so that the state can be cleared?

Comment: Will leave the question up for anyone in future that has the same / a similar issue, my issue was caused by the escape characters in the @timestamp column \"new.dict.@timestamp\" etc. these were being treated as strings not columns

Comment: Do you know if its possible to execute the JOIN operation inside the SQL?

Comment: @ViníciusMatheusOlivieri As in use a join as you would do in normal sql? Yeah it is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will leave the question up for anyone in future that has the same / a similar issue, my issue was caused by the escape characters in the @timestamp column

```
\"new.dict.@timestamp\"
```

etc. these were being treated as strings not columns